# interop Word c# замена слов

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

Я методом Find заменяю некоторые слова, потом сохраняю ворд как пдф, но мне так надо сделать 100 раз. И что бы не сохранять изменения а получить обратно исходный ворд приходится его закрывать без сохранения и опять открывать и так 100 раз. Это очень медленно. Можно ли как то не закрывая ворд откатить изменения?
FindAndReplace(wordApp, replaceRules[item]);

```
                aDoc.SaveAs2(Path, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);

                aDoc.Close(false);
                aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false, NoEncodingDialog: true);
                aDoc.Activate();
                doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
               ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
               ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
```

Comment: Наверняка есть какая-то функции по копированию текущего содержимого. Копируете содержимое, заменяете, вставляете исходный вариант.

Comment: [Undo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.undo?view=word-pia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Alexander Petrov за ответ. Метод Undo в моем случае идеально работает.

```
aDoc.SaveAs2(Path, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);

            aDoc.Close(false);
            aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false, NoEncodingDialog: true);
            aDoc.Activate();
            doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
           ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
           ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);

aDoc.Undo(10);
```